# Creating new columns using text from data frame names within a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that will add new columns to all data frames within a specific list based off the name of each data frame. I have my code working when I test it on one list, but I can't convert it into a function to then apply to all data frames in the list. I'm new to R so I haven't been able to come up with a simpler version other than showing my code.

Below is my code that works for one data frame within the list. In this code, bulkTCRlist2 is the name of my list, with Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv being one data frame within the list.

```
bulkTCRlist2$Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv <- mutate(bulkTCRlist2$Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv,subject=
       substr(deparse(substitute(Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv)),1,6),
     bulkTCRlist2$Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv,year=
       substr(deparse(substitute(Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv)),8,11),
     bulkTCRlist2$Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv,day=
       substr(deparse(substitute(Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv)),13,14),
     bulkTCRlist2$Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv,state=
       substr(deparse(substitute(Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv)),16,18),
     bulkTCRlist2$Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv,sort=
       substr(deparse(substitute(Sbj_05_2016_d0_active_bk.tsv)),23,24))
```

The code I have used to try to convert it into a function is below.

```
bulkTCRname <- function(df){bulkTCRlist3 <- df %>%  mutate(df,subject=
       substr(deparse(substitute(list(df))),1,6),
     df,year=
       substr(deparse(substitute(df)),8,11),
     df,day=
       substr(deparse(substitute(df)),13,14),
     df,state=
       substr(deparse(substitute(df)),16,18),
     df,sort=
       substr(deparse(substitute(df)),23,24))bulkTCRlist3}

bulkTCRlist3 <- lapply(bulkTCRlist2,bulkTCRname)
```

This adds the columns, but the data in the columns is blank or incorrect.. How do I get it to use the name of the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared a reproducible example to test this but you can iterate over the names of the list or it's index. So try something like :

```
bulkTCRlist3 <- lapply(names(bulkTCRlist2),bulkTCRname)
```

where in `bulkTCRname` to get the dataframe you can use `[[` :

```
bulkTCRname <- function(df_name) {
       bulkTCRlist2[[df_name]]
       #Add your code here
}
```

The same should also work if you pass an index instead

```
bulkTCRlist3 <- lapply(seq_along(bulkTCRlist2),bulkTCRname)
```